# Selenium.IsElementPresent using a Select Option's text (C#)

Tags: c#, xpath, selenium, selenium-rc

I'm using Selenium in C# with Selenium RC to do some automated interaction testing but have come across a stumbling block.

Given this HTML:

```
<select id="my-select-list">
    <option value="1">First option</option>
    <option value="2">Second option</option>
    <option value="3">Third option</option>
    <option value="4">Fourth option</option>
</select>
```

I want to test to make sure that the option "Third Option" is present on the page.

All of the following tests have failed, i.e. return false:

```
Selenium.IsElementPresent("//select/option[@label='Third option']")
Selenium.IsElementPresent("//select[option='Third option']")
Selenium.IsElementPresent("//select[contains(option, 'Third option')]")
Selenium.IsElementPresent("//option[contains(., 'Third option')]")
Selenium.IsElementPresent("//option[contains(text(), 'Third option')]")
```

Is it a limitation of Selenium (RC / .NET) or is there another way of selecting it?

Ps. I know I could test using the option's value but that may change and the text definately won't.

**EDIT: PEBKAC error**

Sorry, my bad. Seems selenium was loading a different site than what I thought it was loading.

The following XPath queries all work:

```
Selenium.IsElementPresent("//option[text()='Third option']")
Selenium.IsElementPresent("//select[option='Third option']")
Selenium.IsElementPresent("//option[contains(., 'Third option')]")
Selenium.IsElementPresent("//option[contains(text(), 'Third option')]")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My XPath's a bit rusty, but have you tried...

```
Selenium.IsElementPresent("//option[text()='Third option']");
```

Comment: PEBKAC error, my bad. Selenium was loading a different site than I thought it was. I'll give you the answer anyway, because you were correct :-)

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Getting All Options in the Drop Down

Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("my-select-list")));
String [] options = select.getOptions();

Step 2: Checking Weather the Specific Option("Third Option") is present in the Drop Down.

for(String option:options)

{

if(!option.equals("Third option"))

FAIL;

else

PASS;

}